# Case-insensitive string startswith in Python

Tags: python, string, performance, case-insensitive, startswith

Here is how I check whether `mystring` begins with some string:

```
>>> mystring.lower().startswith("he")
True
```

The problem is that `mystring` is very long (thousands of characters), so the `lower()` operation takes a lot of time.

**QUESTION:** Is there a more efficient way?

My unsuccessful attempt:

```
>>> import re;
>>> mystring.startswith("he", re.I)
False
```

Comment: Thanks.  I benefited from your 'problematic' example.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You could use a regular expression as follows:

```
In [33]: bool(re.match('he', 'Hello', re.I))
Out[33]: True 

In [34]: bool(re.match('el', 'Hello', re.I))
Out[34]: False
```

On a 2000-character string this is about 20x times faster than `lower()`:

```
In [38]: s = 'A' * 2000

In [39]: %timeit s.lower().startswith('he')
10000 loops, best of 3: 41.3 us per loop

In [40]: %timeit bool(re.match('el', s, re.I))
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.06 us per loop
```

If you are matching the same prefix repeatedly, pre-compiling the regex can make a large difference:

```
In [41]: p = re.compile('he', re.I)

In [42]: %timeit p.match(s)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 351 ns per loop
```

For short prefixes, slicing the prefix out of the string before converting it to lowercase could be even faster:

```
In [43]: %timeit s[:2].lower() == 'he'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 287 ns per loop
```

Relative timings of these approaches will of course depend on the length of the prefix. On my machine the breakeven point seems to be about six characters, which is when the pre-compiled regex becomes the fastest method.

In my experiments, checking every character separately could be even faster:

```
In [44]: %timeit (s[0] == 'h' or s[0] == 'H') and (s[1] == 'e' or s[1] == 'E')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 189 ns per loop
```

However, this method only works for prefixes that are known when you're writing the code, and doesn't lend itself to longer prefixes.

Comment: Your test is a bit wrong, as you do not include the time of `re.complie()`

Comment: @BasicWolf: The key is in *"If you are matching the same prefix repeatedly..."*. What it's saying is that the cost of the compile (~900ns) gets amortised across many matches and becomes negligible.

Comment: Note that this really only works for the trivial cases, since Python's regex implementation is sadly not compliant with the actual Unicode standard. To name just one example, in a case insensitive comparison `ß == SS`  should be true, but `re.match('ß', 'SS', re.I)` does not match. To be fair the lower() solution is just as incorrect, so no big harm there.

Answer (score 37):

How about this:

```
prefix = 'he'
if myVeryLongStr[:len(prefix)].lower() == prefix.lower()
```

Comment: Interesting idea.

Answer (score 10):

Another simple solution is to pass a **tuple** to `startswith()` for all the cases needed to match e.g. `.startswith(('case1', 'case2', ..))`.

For example:

```
>>> 'Hello'.startswith(('He', 'HE'))
True
>>> 'HEllo'.startswith(('He', 'HE'))
True
>>>
```

Comment: That's unlikely to happen in the real world when both strings are typically coming from external source... Also generating all options is extremely inefficient (2^n options for string of length n)

Answer (score 4):

None of the given answers is actually correct, as soon as you consider anything outside the ASCII range.

For example in a case insensitive comparison `ß` should be considered equal to `SS` if you're following Unicode's case mapping rules.

To get correct results the easiest solution is to install Python's [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module which follows the standard:

```
import re
import regex
# enable new improved engine instead of backwards compatible v0
regex.DEFAULT_VERSION = regex.VERSION1 

print(re.match('ß', 'SS', re.IGNORECASE)) # none
print(regex.match('ß', 'SS', regex.IGNORECASE)) # matches
```

Comment: Re: your comment on german language stack about "noob." I just wanted to tell you there's no "statue of limitations." :D it's a statuTe!

Comment: @buttle Swype very much disagrees with that. Although I do like the idea of a statue ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the performance of .lower(), if prefix was small enough it might be faster to check equality multiple times:

```
s =  'A' * 2000
prefix = 'he'
ch0 = s[0] 
ch1 = s[1]
substr = ch0 == 'h' or ch0 == 'H' and ch1 == 'e' or ch1 == 'E'
```

Timing (using the same string as NPE):

```
>>> timeit.timeit("ch0 = s[0]; ch1 = s[1]; ch0 == 'h' or ch0 == 'H' and ch1 == 'e' or ch1 == 'E'", "s = 'A' * 2000")
0.2509511683747405

= 0.25 us per loop
```

Compared to existing method:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("s.lower().startswith('he')", "s = 'A' * 2000", number=10000)
0.6162763703208611

= 61.63 us per loop
```

(This is horrible, of course, but if the code is extremely performance critical then it might be worth it)

Comment: Of course using Python is pretty much dumb in the first place if those milliseconds count like that.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.8, the fastest solution involves slicing and comparing the prefix, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13578990/631596):

```py
def startswith(a_source: str, a_prefix: str) -> bool:
    source_prefix = a_source[:len(a_prefix)]
    return source_prefix.casefold() == a_prefix.casefold()
```

The second fastest solution uses ctypes (e.g., [_wcsicmp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/stricmp-wcsicmp-mbsicmp-stricmp-l-wcsicmp-l-mbsicmp-l).) *Note: This is a Windows example.*

```py
import ctypes.util

libc_name = ctypes.util.find_library('msvcrt')
libc = ctypes.CDLL(libc_name)

libc._wcsicmp.argtypes = (ctypes.c_wchar_p, ctypes.c_wchar_p)

def startswith(a_source: str, a_prefix: str) -> bool:
    source_prefix = a_source[:len(a_prefix)]
    return libc._wcsicmp(source_prefix, a_prefix) == 0
```

The [compiled `re` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13578943/631596) is the third fastest solution, including the cost of compilation. That solution is even slower if the `regex` module is used for full Unicode support, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42954601/631596). Each successive match costs around the same as each of the ctypes calls.

`lower()` and `casefold()` are expensive because these functions create new Unicode strings by iterating over each character in the source strings, regardless of case, and mapping them accordingly. (See: [How is the built-in function `str.lower()` implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41975752/631596)) The time spent in that loop increases with each character, so if you're dealing with short prefixes and long strings, call these functions on only the prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
import re
o = re.search('(?i)^we', 'Wednesday')
print(o != None)
```

https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.I